# Warning "not on PATH" when I tried to install python extensions. I'm new to Linux -- what does this mean?

Tags: ubuntu, python, path

When I tried to add python extension to vscode, it showed that some extension(?) was absent and automatically prompted the following command `/bin/python3 /home/myusername/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.9.112786/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U pylint --user`

However, after I ran it in the terminal, although the installation was successful, it shows

`WARNING: The script isort is installed in '/home/myusername/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.`

Is this a serious problem? What should I do?

Comment: IIRC the default Ubuntu `~/.profile` adds `$HOME/.local/bin` to the `PATH` if it exists - so if it *is* a problem, it is probably one that will resolve itself after logging off and back on

Answer (score 5):

`PATH` is an environment variable containing a colon-separated list of directories that `bash` uses to find executable programs when you type commands.

If what you type doesn't match an `alias` or function or a `bash` builtin, `bash` searches the list of directories in `PATH` for an executable.

Add your directory to `$PATH` for the current process with

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
```

on the command line.

To make the change permanent, add the above line to your `$HOME/.bashrc`.

Comment: Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.